# Run a program through batch file and then execute something using that program

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I'm trying to make a call to a program called kxshell and then run my script using kxshell
So in my batch file I wrote

Kxshell.exe
Read testscript.kxs

But as soon as the batch file executes the exe, it starts the kxshell prompt and doesn't run the read command.  Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Do what Jon said below or provide a link to this Kxshell program.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a manual for kxshell.exe? Sounds like the command line options you're providing aren't correct.

You can just go start -> run -> cmd.exe and try different command lines until it works and then use that command line in your batch file.